# How do I use an env file with GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions

I have multiple environments (dev, qa, prod) and I'm using .env files to store secrets etc... Now I'm switching to GitHub Actions, and I want to use my .env files and declare them into the `env` section of the github actions yml.

But from what I've seen so far, it seems that I can not set a file path and I have to manually re-declare all variables.

How should I proceed as best practice?

Comment: Hi OP! Any luck on this? I'm facing the same issue with Github Actions as well -- trying to figure out a way to somehow store secret variables by different environments.

Comment: Basically you have to manually copy the content of the respective .env files (say `.env.stage`, `.env.production`) into the respective GitHub Actions secret variables (say `WEBSITE_ENV_STAGE`, `WEBSITE_ENV_PRODUCTION`). Then at your GitHub Actions workflow script create the `.env` file from the desired variable like this `echo "${{ secrets.WEBSITE_ENV_STAGE }}" > .env` and use it in the workflow.

Comment: I have 2 more ways for you to use `.env` files in your project. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67543246/6597265).

Answer (score 224, accepted):

A quick solution here could be having a step to manually create the `.env` file before you need it.

```
      - name: 'Create env file'
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo API_ENDPOINT="https://xxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" >> .env
          echo API_KEY=${{ secrets.API_KEY }} >> .env
          cat .env
```

Comment: We have the same solution but this is cumbersome, I have 36 env variables to edit.

Comment: Had to remove the extra > for it to work

Comment: When trying to use this solution I kept getting the following error: `line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'. I was able to work around it by passing in the secrets separately. I posted the code below.

Comment: Do I need to paste this step before 'Checkout the repo' or where? It seems for me the only solution was to upload my .env files to the repository - as even I created env file in this step it did not see in `npm run build`

Comment: @aRtoo You can paste your entire env file in one secret named `ENV_FILE` and the just do `echo "${{ secrets.ENV_FILE }}" > .env`. I updated the answer with a slightly better approach

Comment: > Better method for multiple variables.  -It's really practical for many variables. Thank you!

Comment: Can I put a yaml file in secrets and use the same echo to create the yaml file on runtime?

Comment: Caution: **Never use structured data as a secret**. 
Structured data can cause secret redaction within logs to fail, because redaction largely relies on finding an exact match for the specific secret value. For example, do not use a blob of JSON, XML, or YAML (or similar) to encapsulate a secret value, as this significantly reduces the probability the secrets will be properly redacted. Instead, create individual secrets for each sensitive value. ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-secrets

Comment: @DollarAkshay you shouldn't be adding your own content when you edit, but rather updating the language for clarity. Your addition belongs in another answer entirely.

Comment: The first solution personally worked for me the best ;) Thx

Answer (score 41):

I would suggest 3 pretty simple ways to engage your `.env` file variables in the GitHub Actions workflow. They differ based on whether you store the file in your repository (the worst practice) or keep it out of it (the best practice).

1. You keep your `.env` file in the repository:

   - There are some [ready-made actions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=github+actions+dotenv&atb=v242-1&ia=web&iai=r1-1&page=1&sexp=%7B%22biaexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22msvrtexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22earlydeep%22%3A%22a%22%7D) that allow to read the `.env` variables (e.g. [Dotenv Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dotenv-action),[Simple Dotenv](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/simple-dotenv)).
2. (*simple, manual, annoying when update `.env` variables*) You keep your file out of your repository (keep there and maintain updated `.env.example` instead):

   - You manually copy the content of the respective `.env`    files (say `.env.stage`, `.env.production`) into the respective GitHub Actions [secret variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) (say `WEBSITE_ENV_STAGE`, `WEBSITE_ENV_PRODUCTION`).
   - Then at your GitHub Actions workflow script create the `.env` file from the desired variable like this `echo "${{secrets.WEBSITE_ENV_STAGE }}" > .env` and use it in the workflow.
3. (*a bit more involved though prepare it once, then change your `.env` variables at the local machine, then sync these at GitHub with one click*) As in item 2 above, the file is out of the repository.

   - Now you use the GitHub Actions API to [create or update the secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-or-update-a-repository-secret). On your local machine in the `dev` environment you write the NodeJS script that calls the API endpoint and write the `.env` files to the desired GitHub Actions secret variable (say as above into `WEBSITE_ENV_STAGE` or to both stage and production variables at once);

This is pretty wide choice of ways to engage the `.env` files's variables in the workflow. Use any matching your preference and circumstances.

Just for information, there is the 4th way which engages some 3rd party services like [Dotenv Vault](https://www.dotenv.org/vault) or [HasiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) (there are more of the kind) where you keep you secret variables to read these to create `.env` file at build time with your CI/CD pipeline. Read there for details.

Comment: Keeping your .env in the repo is bad practice and a potential security issue, especially when having AWS credentials or any sort of cloud provider credentials.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum I mentioned this explicitly in my answer. Despite putting `.env` files in VCS being the worst practce, it is used by many in reality. As well as many other worst practices.

Comment: Hi @ValentineShi, thanks for sharing this great answer with us. It inspired me to create my first action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/next-env. It loads and provides .env variables using Next.js' @next/env package. This means it takes care of loading .env, .env.development, .env.development.local (and other files Next.js uses for environment variables) in your GitHub Action in the correct order (defined by Next.js).

Comment: How do I deploy to different environments from a release branch for production and main branch for dev?

Comment: can you provide the full workflow yaml? I donj't know where to put `echo "${{secrets.WEBSITE_ENV_STAGE }}" > .env`

Comment: @chovy You may use [`on`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) YAML command to run an Actions workflow on, say, some branch push. From there you can decide what steps your workflow should engage (where to deploy etc.). You can use multiple workflows from multiple git branches.  To run bash scripts (e.g. to `echo` something somewhere) in the workflow use [`run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/essential-features-of-github-actions), Look at the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions), they are great to my taste.

Comment: Please provide a full example.

Comment: @chovy I have no example handy. This is all pretty basic, you could infer what you need from the docs examples. You could find the examples in the other answers as well.

Comment: there is a 4th option too. Upload the env to private S3 bucket, download it from S3 inside your github action

Answer (score 39):

The easiest way to do this is to create the .env file as a github secret and then create the .env file in your action.
So step 1 is to create the .env files as a secret in github as a base64 encoded string:
`openssl base64 -A -in qa.env -out qa.txt`
or
`cat qa.env | base64 -w 0 > qa.txt`
Then in you action, you can do something like

```
- name: Do Something with env files
  env:
    QA_ENV_FILE: ${{ secrets.QA_ENV_FILE }}
    PROD_ENV_FILE: ${{ secrets.PROD_ENV_FILE }}
  run: |
    [ "$YOUR_ENVIRONMENT" = qa ] && echo $QA_ENV_FILE | base64 --decode > .env
    [ "$YOUR_ENVIRONMENT" = prod ] && echo $PROD_ENV_FILE | base64 --decode > .env
```

There are a number of ways for determining `$YOUR_ENVIRONMENT` but usually this can be extracted from the `GITHUB_REF` object.  You applications should be able to read from the .env files as needed.

Comment: Aren't Github secrets already encrypted? It seems like you're encrypting an encrypted file, and Github is already doing the decryption to read the secrets file.

Comment: @Brettins the `.env` file here possibly contains many keys. The point of encoding them into a string is so you don't need to declare each and every one on github secrets.

Comment: @brian , this actually seems to be the perfect solution for my case, however im confused about the openssl command where do we need to run this command?

Comment: @uneebmeer you can run that in your terminal to generate the base64 version string.

Comment: @munsu very nice solution. We don't need to set every env keys through your way.

Comment: This may not be secure. Your secrets will be exposed in logs and such.  *Redaction largely relies on finding an exact match for the specific secret value*. Meaning, if you decode it and use the values here and there, GitHub won't be able to detect tha. Because its will not match that encoded string. ref  https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-secrets

Answer (score 10):

Edit:
You were using Circleci Contexts, so with that you had a set of secrets of each env. I know they are working to bring secrets to org level, and maybe team level... there is no info if they will create sort of contexts like we have in CCI.

I have thought on adding the env as prefix of the secret name like STAGE_GITHUB_KEY or INTEGRATION_GITHUB_KEY using ${env}_GITHUB_KEY on the yml as a workaround for now... What do you think?

--- Original answer:
If I understand you well, you already have the dotenv files stored somewhere and you want to inject all those secrets into the steps, without having to manually add them to github secrets and do the mapping in each workflow you migrate... right?

There is an action made by someone that reads a dotenv file and put its values into ouputs, so you can use them linked in further steps. Here is the link: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dotenv-action

Whatever is present in the .env file will be converted into an output variable. For example .env file with content:

```
VERSION=1.0
AUTHOR=Mickey Mouse
```

You do:

```
id: dotenv
uses: ./.github/actions/dotenv-action
```

Then later you can refer to the alpine version like this ${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.version }}

Comment: where would be that .env file? Since it's not saved in the repo - which is the point of having a .env file

Comment: well, it looks like a common pattern (to have a .env file that is being read by a CI task -- see for example https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/anilanar/dotenv). This answer looks like a good match for your question, IF you can supply a variable as the `path` of the task.

Comment: @HRK44 With "and I want to use my .env files" I understand you had them already, I thought in S3 or something. If you have them and are looking for storing securely, you can store in S3 and use aws secret+key to download and add to the action. If not, you have to generate them printing github secrets into a file with sed replacing placeholders or doing a simple echo to the file, whatever you like.

If not the case, please clarify your scenario.

nilleb He is migrating from Circleci to Github, so the orb is not useful in this case

Comment: @Ayo well in CircleCi we had the envs stored in CircleCi, we have multiple versions of the env (dev, qa, prod, etc...) but in GitHub actions we can store only one version of the secrets. Right now we are using Jenkins (which has the secrets stored) and depending on the build type, it will use dev/qa/prod secrets. How can we do this with Github Actions?

Comment: Ok I think I got you. You were using Circleci Contexts, so with that you had a set of secrets of each env. I know they are working to bring secrets to org level, and maybe team level... there is no info if they will create sort of contexts like we have in CCI. I have thought on adding the env as prefix of the secret name like STAGE_GITHUB_KEY or INTEGRATION_GITHUB_KEY using ${env}_GITHUB_KEY on the yml as a workaround for now... What do you think?

Comment: @HRK44 If I helped you, do you mind selecting as correct answer? it would help me to start the profile here due to the "min reputation" limitations :-) thanks

Comment: @Ayo brilliant!! thank you!! that workaround helped me :D

Comment: @Ayo update your answer with your comment and i'll accept it for now

Comment: @HRK44 done thank you :-) Im new in terms of posting answers

Answer (score 9):

You can also use a dedicated `github action` from github-marketplace to create `.env` files.

Example usage:

```
name: Create envfile

on: [push]

jobs:

  create-envfile:
 
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
 
    steps:
    - name: Make envfile
      uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
      with:
        envkey_DEBUG: false
        envkey_SOME_API_KEY: "123456abcdef"
        envkey_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
        file_name: .env
```

Depending on your values defined for secrets in github repo, this will create a `.env` file like below:

```
DEBUG: false
SOME_API_KEY: "123456abcdef"
SECRET_KEY: password123
```

More info: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-env-file

Comment: This solution is cleaner and simple

Answer (score 4):

You can export all secrets to environment variables and do everything from a script.

I created an action exactly for that - takes all the secrets and exports them to environment variables.

An example would be:

```
- run: echo "Value of MY_SECRET1: $MY_SECRET1"
  env:
    MY_SECRET1: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET1 }}
    MY_SECRET2: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET2 }}
    MY_SECRET3: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET3 }}
    MY_SECRET4: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET4 }}
    MY_SECRET5: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET5 }}
    MY_SECRET6: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET6 }}
    ...
```

You could convert it to:

```
- uses: oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action@v1
  with:
    secrets: ${{ toJSON(secrets) }}
- run: echo "Value of MY_SECRET1: $MY_SECRET1"
```

Link to the action, which contains more documentation about configuration: https://github.com/oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action

Comment: Does this put the all the key:value pair from the env to json format? or this would return a "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type kvflag.FlagJSON"

Comment: this exports all the github secrets to env vars. the JSON you see in the example is for this custom action to read the secrets.

Answer (score 4):

The most modern alternative is to use a `.env.vault` file.

Here's a [NodeJS Guide on how to use a `.env.vault` file with GitHub Actions](https://www.dotenv.org/docs/languages/nodejs/github-actions)

It boils down to 3 steps:

1. Build your encrypted `.env.vault` file and commit that safely to code. This contains an encrypted copy of your CI secrets.
2. Set a single `DOTENV_KEY` environment variable on GitHub Actions
3. When the CI runs it will use the `DOTENV_KEY` to decrypt the contents of your `.env.vault` and inject your environment variables just in time.

This approach is a little more work to initially set up (familiarizing yourself with the new .env.vault file format), but then it has the following benefits:

- No more scattering your secrets across multiple third parties like GitHub Actions that could leak them someday (like what happened with [CircleCi breach](https://techcrunch.com/2023/01/05/circleci-breach/))
- You can manage and check your secrets from one central place (rather than having to check GitHub Actions UI to see the value of a secret)
- If you move CIs everything still just works. You just have to set again that single `DOTENV_KEY`, not a hundred others on the ci server. All your secrets and config are still encrypted inside your `.env.vault` file which lives safely in your repository.
- An attacker needs access to both your `DOTENV_KEY` and your `.env.vault` file to gain access to your secrets/config. So if GitHub Actions ever has a leak of their CI secrets, your secrets will still be safe because the attacker will only have your `DOTENV_KEY` and not your `.env.vault` file. This will save you the time and annoyance of having to rotate all your secrets.

Hope this is useful. Full disclosure: I am the pioneer of [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) and also run the [Dotenv.org](https://dotenv.org) service. That said, the mechanism to generate your `.env.vault` file is completely open, local, and free. It's just a file format that uses AES-256 GCM encryption. I wanted the same (or close to) elegance of a .env file but with added security for production and ci deployments. [See here for how to use the local only commands](https://github.com/dotenv-org/dotenv-vault#how-do-i-use--locally-managed-dotenv-vault) or use [dotenv.org for the hosted solution](https://dotenv.org).

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use the [Environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments) feature from github. Although that isn't available on private repos in the free plan.
You could have scoped variables, at repository, profile/organization level and environment. The configuration variables closer to the repository takes precedence over the others.

Answer (score 3):

Btw you can also do `gh secret set -f .env` if you have the github cli!

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the accepted solution but GitHub actions were complaining about the shell commands. I kept getting this error: ``` line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``' ```

Instead of referencing the secrets directly in the shell script, I had to pass them in separately.

```
  - name: Create env file
    run: |
      touch .env
      echo POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER} >> .env
      echo POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} >> .env
      cat .env
    env: 
      POSTGRES_USER: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_USER }} 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_PASSWORD }}
```

Comment: I think he typed > when he wanted >>

Answer (score 1):

One more approach would be doing something as described in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets

So basically treating your `.env` file as a "large secret". In this case, the encrypted `.env` file is kept commited in your repo, which should be fine. Then in your action have a step to decrypt the `.env` file.

This removes the overhead of having to create each individual secret inside your `.env` as a Github secret. The only Github secret to maintain in this case, is one for the encryption password. If you have multiple `.env` files such as `qa.env`, `prod.env`, etc... I would strongly suggest using a different encryption password for each, and then store each encryption passwords as an "environment secret" in Github instead of "repo secret" (if using Github environments is your thing. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment).

If you don't want to commit the (encrypted) `.env` file in you repo, then I would go with the base64 approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64452700/1806782 (which is simmilar to what's in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#storing-base64-binary-blobs-as-secrets) and then create a new Github secret to host the encoded contents.

For those like me with aversion to manual repetitive tasks, Github secret creation can these days easily be scripted with the Github CLI tool. See
https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_secret_set . It also supports 'batch' creation of secrets from env files (see the `-f`, `--env-file` flags)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. What I wanted was to upload a .env file to my server instead of defining the env variables in my Github repo. Since I was not tracking my .env file so every time my workflow ran the .env file got deleted. So what I did was :

1. Added the `.env` file in the project root directory in my server.
2. Added `clean: false` under `with` key in my `actions/checkout@v2` in my workflow

eg:

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
       
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with: 
        clean: 'false'
```

This prevents git from deleting untracked files like .env. For more info see: [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout)

Answer (score 0):

inspired by [Valentine Shis answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67543246/1238150), I created a GitHub Action for this use-case and the one I had at the time while reading this thread.

GitHub Action: [next-env](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/next-env)

> GitHub Action to read .env.[development|test|production][.local] files in Next.js (but also non Next.js) projects and add variables as secrets to GITHUB_ENV.

Despite the name, it also works in non-Next.js projects as it uses a decoupled package of the Next ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a GitHub Action specifically designed for utilizing your environment variables within your .env files, eliminating the need to set up secrets in GitHub project settings. Check it out here: https://github.com/zdeneklapes/dotenv-vault-action.

It can download the .env file of your choice and will delete all downloaded .env files as a Post Job (after all jobs are completed)!

You still need to set at least 1 secret, it is your `DOTENV_ME`.

### How to load `.env` variables into the environment?

When the `.env` file is downloaded don't forget to load your environment variables using the command `source .env`.

##### Example:

```yaml
- uses: zdeneklapes/dotenv-vault-action@v1
        with:
          dotenvMe: ${{ secrets.DOTENV_ME }}
          stage: "ci"
          move: "false"
- run: |
    source .env.ci
    ssh "${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST}" "
    cd ${DIR_SSH_PROJECT_PRODUCTION} || exit
    docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build
    cd - || exit
    "
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to define your environment variables in "Secrets" section of your repository. Then you can simply use your secrets in your workflow.

Example usage:

```
- uses: some-action@v1
  env:
    API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
    SECRET_ID: ${{ secrets.SECRET_ID }}
  with:
    password: ${{ secrets.MY_PASSWORD }}
```

Here is the documentation:

https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I'm talking about how to handle in the best way multiple environments with this system (dev, qa, stage, prod, etc...) ?