# Github Actions: Can not acces values in properties file

Tags: android, gradle, devops, github-actions

I have some problem to acces secrets variables in build.gradle file. I've defined two secrets in Github repo settings: PUBLIC_API_KEY and PRIVATE_API_KEY

In my actions.yml file I read them from the secrets, decode and write into a apikey.properties file

```
name: My fancy app 

on: [ push, pull_request ]

defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Clone Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Acces API Public Key
        env:
          PUBLIC_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.PUBLIC_API_KEY }}
        run: echo "$PUBLIC_API_KEY" | base64 -d > ./apikey.properties

      - name: Acces API Private Key
        env:
          PRIVATE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_API_KEY }}
        run: echo "$PRIVATE_API_KEY" | base64 -d > ./apikey.properties
```

In my build.gradle I create a properties object from the apikey.properties file and try to read the variables, that where saved in the previous step. This is what is looks like in my build.gradle file

```
def apikeyPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("apikey.properties")
def apikeyProperties = new Properties()
try {
    apikeyProperties.load(new FileInputStream(apikeyPropertiesFile))
    println("Private Key value" + apikeyProperties['PRIVATE_API_KEY'])
    println("Public Key value" + apikeyProperties['PUBLIC_API_KEY'])
} catch(Exception exception) {
    println("Error by loading properties file" + exception.message)
}
....

buildConfigField("String", "PRIVATE_API_KEY", apikeyProperties['PRIVATE_API_KEY'])
buildConfigField("String", "PUBLIC_API_KEY", apikeyProperties['PUBLIC_API_KEY'])
```

The build is failing because both apiKeyProperties values are null.

Can somebody tell me, why the values are null?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350136/4906597) post I found out, that the keys were missing in the apikey.properties file. This is how my fix looks like:

```
....
 - name: Acces API Keys
        run: |
          touch apikey.properties
          echo PUBLIC_API_KEY=${{ secrets.PUBLIC_API_KEY }} >> apikey.properties
          echo PRIVATE_API_KEY=${{ secrets.PRIVATE_API_KEY }} >> apikey.properties
          cat apikey.properties
...
```

Comment: under what path is your apikey.properties (resource folder)?