# Override variables in environment file via GitHub Actions script

Tags: github-actions

I copy my `.env.example` file:

```yaml
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
```

But I also want to have override variables in the `.env` file. I have tried:

```yaml
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
      env:
        DB_DATABASE: test_db
        DB_USER: root
        DB_PASSWORD: root
```

But the new variables I assign in the [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) file do not override variables in the `.env` file. How can I override variables in my `.env` file in the Actions script?

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect that they would - all you're doing there is copying a file. Set the env map in the step where those variables are actually _used_.

Comment: I have also tried to use those  new `env` in the step used, it still uses the ones from the original `env` file.

Comment: Could you give a [mre] _of that_? What you've shown here isn't going to work because the `env` is only set _for that step_, and they're not actually _used_ in the copy operation. I suppose you could add to the `.env` file after copying it, as shown in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350136/3001761, which _would_ use the env vars set in this step.