# Access GitHub Secrets in local env file

Tags: environment-variables, local, github-secret

Is there a way to access GitHub secrets in a local env file? So instead of having a secret saved directly in the env file it would reference a GitHub secret. I've seen that the GitHub secrets can be used within a workflow but I mainly just need to have the values in the env file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing things.

A local env file does not access variables, instead, your code reads the env file and uses those variables.

If you use something like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv), this tool will read your env files, and optionally override them if you defined the variables directly on the environment.

You can use an action workflow (disclosure: i'm the author) that exports your github secrets as env variables, so last part (overrides) would just work.

An example would be:

```
- run: echo "Value of MY_SECRET1: $MY_SECRET1"
  env:
    MY_SECRET1: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET1 }}
    MY_SECRET2: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET2 }}
    MY_SECRET3: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET3 }}
    MY_SECRET4: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET4 }}
    MY_SECRET5: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET5 }}
    MY_SECRET6: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET6 }}
    ...
```

You could convert it to:

```
- uses: oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action@v1
  with:
    secrets: ${{ toJSON(secrets) }}
- run: echo "Value of MY_SECRET1: $MY_SECRET1"
```

Link to the action, which contains more documentation about configuration: https://github.com/oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action

See this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176044/how-do-i-use-an-env-file-with-github-actions).